# pip can't find required versions

Tags: python, pip, freeze, pypi

I recently finished a project working in a fresh conda environment. During development I downloaded packages as required. I created a requirements.txt file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Now I'm trying to reproduce that environment on a web server. This web server automatically calls `pip install -r requirements.txt` to download the required packages. However this process fails on many of the dependencies with

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ...

From what I can tell the version numbers listed in the requirements.txt file are much higher than those on PyPI.

As an example, the requirements.txt file calls for mkl-fft==1.0.15 (optimizations to NumPy) but PyPI only lists up to version [1.0.6](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/). The [mkl-fft github](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft/blob/master/CHANGES.rst) has up to version 1.1.

I think this is the discrepancy causing the "Could not find a version that satisfies..." error. Can anyone confirm?

I can remove the version number and pip will download the latest version it can find, but I have 5-6 packages like this. Given that other packages are expecting these versions (e.g. numpy works with mkl-fft) mismatching the versions results in runtime failures in the replicated environment.

Is there a fix to help pip install get the specified versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that (some) packages provided by conda have hight version numbers than the ones available from pypi. For example, with mkl-fft:

- [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/) has version 1.0.6
- [Conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mkl_fft) has version 1.1.0

If you created your dev environment using conda, you should probably based your prod environment on conda as well - using `conda list --export` to create the requirements, and `conda create --name <envname> --file requirements.txt` to replicate the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yes, I'm looking into creating the production environment from conda but my first few choices are coming up short. It's not possible in python anywhere and it looks like there are a lot if issues with that approach in Heroku as well. I'll keep looking...

Comment: If my answer satisfies your needs - could you please accept it for future generations?

Comment: @ACasey try to make your python environment using pipenv or venv in your system and install all packages using pip, then you can replicate same on server, otherwise you need to install anaconda in server itself